# ¿Cómo ver las solicitudes HTTPS en IIS?

Tags: iis

¿como puedo ver un listado de las ultimas solicitudes https en IIS?

Por ejemplo, en Linux con cPanel puedo ver las ultimas solicitudes de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Se puede hacer algo parecido en IIS?**

Answer (score 0):

La verdad que hace tiempo q no uso un IIS, pero por lo q puedo recordar habia q instalar el Request Monitor. [Encontré esta imagen que puede ayudar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKgXx.png)